Incorrect calculations from java file, using File object
public class Driver {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //what is this?  
    System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
    String filename = scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    File myFile = new File(filename);
    scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    // yearly sum for all branches
    double yearlySum = 0;
    //quarterly sum for all branches
    //initialised to 0 by default
    double[] quarterlySum = new double[4]; //??
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
        
        double sales = scan.nextDouble();
        yearlySum += sales;
        //quarterly 0, 1, 2 and 3
        int quarter = count % 4;
        quarterlySum[quarter] += sales;
        count++;        
    }
    
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(yearlySum);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println(quarterlySum[i]);        
    }
        
    }
}

this is the TXT I am using
1   1274.0  1585.0  1820.5  2038.4
2   1164.0  897.2   1432.8
3   987.4   1106.7  897.5   2137.2

this is the console
15346.7
4369.7
3416.2
3736.4
3824.3999999999996

I have copied this code from a tutorial so am unsure about a few things
the first double on the console should I'm assuming be the sum of all doubles from the TXT, which would be under the variable yearlySum.
According to my calculations this would be 15,340.7 NOT 15346.7

the first of the array which I'm assuming adds all three first index's of the lines should be 3,425.4 NOT 4369.7

the next should be 3,588.9 NOT 3416.2

the next should be 4,150.8 NOT 3736.4

the next should be 4,175.6 NOT 3824.3999999999996


Whats the problem with the code?
this is the tutorial I followed though the TXT file is a little different
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJ1x5gcAoYs&list=PLtQo0sxRN7JKKla3_GAF05dySjyy3nINa&index=23&ab_channel=BeginCodingFast
Any help would be greatly appreachiated
I tried changing TXT numbers which did not have a decimal point to have a .0

11 values in the file

the values 1, 2 and 3 are probably not intended to be in the file, just displayed line numbers (1+2+3=6 the sum difference) ||| also, apparently the second line is missing the fourth value (posted code is not considering lines)

@g00se 14 values though

(as often, video is not the best format for programming tutorials; IMO text is better)

@Siguza I'm assuming the integers are line numbers

You haven't really grasped this I feel. The figures represent quarterly sales for three branches. So you need to sum each line for each branch to get annual totals

@g00se they were probably supposed to be... but they're still present in the file, and the code doesn't skip over them. 1 + 2038.4 + 1432.8 + 897.5 = 4369.7

1, 2, 3 have now been removed, the TXT has equal spacing, I'm still getting incorrect calculations. Any ideas?

Now considering each line, 1 — 3 as a single branch and each double on each branch a quarter (the missing fourth quarter in branch 2 is intentional). I'm assuming that the idea is to total the values in position 1 across all three lines and so on and add them to the array index.

I'm assuming that the idea is ... Why "assume" - it's you who posted the video (which I hope you watched) link ;) I didn't watch it beyond looking at the video frame(s) which contained the image of the (intact) file

Solved, blank must be specified as 0.0 in TXT to prevent next double from going into the next index and causing the array to become out of sync.
